# Medium-Chain Triglycerides for weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss, nutrition

I have recently heard of several use cases of [Medium-Chain Triglycerides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-chain_triglycerides) for somewhat rapid weight loss.  Seeing [this seemingly corroborated anecdote](http://paleohacks.com/questions/205035/coffee-and-mct-experiment-cant-ketosis-and-carbs-j.html) got me started down this thought process.  I then discovered an actual protocol on [BulletProofExec.com](http://www.bulletproofexec.com/rapid-fat-loss-protocol/) that seems to take the cake.

My wife and I have experimented so far with MCT consumption and we've already verified that it does kick your body into ketosis. She had some (fascinating) serious allergic reactions in her arms where she has received allergy shots for the past couple years in the surrounding tissue / fatty stores there.  This should not have happened and the doctors had no explanation as to why it occurred, but we realized afterwards that she had just taken her first does of MCTs an hour before this kicked her butt.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of protocol good or bad?  And does anyone have any ideas of what kind of physical activity / exercise during this kind of protocol would be appropriate?

Comment: I don't have any experience with this, but there really are no shortcuts or magic bullets.  It's just that some eating plans work better with some people than others.

Comment: so was mine the answer? @ylluminate

Comment: So my wife and I actually started intermittent fasting (not what that protocol suggest, but similar) and we're losing amazing amounts of weight as well.  I actually did the rapid fat loss protocol for 2 weeks and lost 15 pounds initially. We see ketosis kick in at about 30 minutes after taking the MCT oil.  We don't use coffee, but we do frequently take a part of a caffeine pill to speed things up.

Comment: That is awesome news. So when you wake up in the morning you're fasted right? Then you take MCT oil, and you're saying this pushes you further into ketosis in your experience?

Comment: Yes, that's generally the case. Amazing stuff!  I also had thinning hair and after this regrew about 25% of my hair over a month.  I started adding collagen to my diet (to actually help rebuild my arteries) and now I have virtually no hair loss on top of that.  Very interesting experiences here!  Might start a blog about this journey. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, so currently I do something called Intermittent Fasting.

I have an eating window of 12-1pm through 8-9pm. The rest of the time, I just drink water, coffee, a diet soda here and there, or tea.

I have had bulletproof Coffee. A Keurig cup of coffee, a tablespoon or two of Coconut oil, throw them in a magic bullet, and blend together. AMAZING.

I have received energy boosts from it in the morning, although its somewhat greasy around your mouth afterward cause of the oil.

Your body is actually usually in ketosis, the question you want to consider is how many ketones your body is producing, getting Ketostix is one way to do this. I think the higher the number the more INTO ketosis you are.

I have found that low-carb or extremely low-carb with carb cycling is somewhat efficient, but you have to eat carbs after 3 days, because your body will only optimally burn fat for a few days in ketosis, then it goes into starvation.

The magic bullet that Berin mentioned is Intermittent Fasting. I am doing a www.leangains.com style of IF 16-fast/8-eat. Cut out snacking, make my meals count, stay on your macros, but most of all stay in a caloric deficit. I lost 8 lbs in two weeks, and retained my strength, by IF and strength training 5-6 days a week. No cardio. I have increased my insulin sensitivity, i feel great...

Anyways, Bulletproof coffee is definitely a good choice. The reason it is ok during the fast is because the fats it releases into your blood stream doesn't spike your insulin. Protein can effect your insulin, obviously carbs do too...but the MCT works great due to the caffeine and rapid fat transport activation when you ingest it, giving way to immediate energy.

Comment: Something fascinating that I just found out yesterday is that this (perhaps these) diets are actually recommended to cancer patients with *amazing* success.  Here is one such [study by Professor Thomas Seyfried, Ph.D.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=sBjnWfT8HbQ)